# How to use lubridate to create rows for missing participant data (longitudinal study)?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to use lubridate to create separate 'start dates' for each participant. then I want lubridate to automatically generate 1 week intervals that correspond to the 'Week number' col.

What I'm trying to do:

while (week number = 1) set data$time to 1
while (week number = 2) set data$time to 2
...
while (week number = 25) set date$time to 25

create interval of 7 days from time 1, so that each participant has 25 rows (1 for each week). If a participant skipped week 3, for example, they would still have a week 3 row, but the values would be empty.

```
while (mydata$Weeknum == "Week1") {
       mydata$time1 <- mydata$RecorededDate

}

int <- int.start(mydata$start_time, 7days)
```

In this code the while loop is bugging out and after that I am stuck as to what to do to match the interval to the week number. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
structure(list(Weeknum = c("Week1", "Week1", "Week1", "Week1", 
"Week1", "Week1"), V1 = structure(c(NA, 1544891009, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10380f2e0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show us how your data looks by providing us first few lines of your data?

Comment: The `dput` you have shared is incomplete so cannot use it. If there are lot of columns you can subset only the columns that are important for this question. `dput(droplevels(df[1:6, 1:4]))`

Comment: I updated it to show what I got when I used the code: dput(head(droplevels(mydataframe[(RecipientLastName), (RecordedDate.y), (Weeknum)]))). (when i didn't use head it was too long to copy) recipientlastname is the participant id

Answer (score 2):

You don't need loops or lubridate:

```r
seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "week", length = 10)
#>  [1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-15" "2020-01-22" "2020-01-29"
#>  [6] "2020-02-05" "2020-02-12" "2020-02-19" "2020-02-26" "2020-03-04"
```

If you have a number of different start dates, and you want to make a single long vector with 25 weeks from each start date, you can do:

```r
# Example start dates
start_dates <- as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-03-04", "2019-03-02"))

do.call(c, lapply(start_dates, seq, by = "week", length.out = 25))
#>  [1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-15" "2020-01-22" "2020-01-29"
#>  [6] "2020-02-05" "2020-02-12" "2020-02-19" "2020-02-26" "2020-03-04"
#> [11] "2020-03-11" "2020-03-18" "2020-03-25" "2020-04-01" "2020-04-08"
#> [16] "2020-04-15" "2020-04-22" "2020-04-29" "2020-05-06" "2020-05-13"
#> [21] "2020-05-20" "2020-05-27" "2020-06-03" "2020-06-10" "2020-06-17"
#> [26] "2020-03-04" "2020-03-11" "2020-03-18" "2020-03-25" "2020-04-01"
#> [31] "2020-04-08" "2020-04-15" "2020-04-22" "2020-04-29" "2020-05-06"
#> [36] "2020-05-13" "2020-05-20" "2020-05-27" "2020-06-03" "2020-06-10"
#> [41] "2020-06-17" "2020-06-24" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-08" "2020-07-15"
#> [46] "2020-07-22" "2020-07-29" "2020-08-05" "2020-08-12" "2020-08-19"
#> [51] "2019-03-02" "2019-03-09" "2019-03-16" "2019-03-23" "2019-03-30"
#> [56] "2019-04-06" "2019-04-13" "2019-04-20" "2019-04-27" "2019-05-04"
#> [61] "2019-05-11" "2019-05-18" "2019-05-25" "2019-06-01" "2019-06-08"
#> [66] "2019-06-15" "2019-06-22" "2019-06-29" "2019-07-06" "2019-07-13"
#> [71] "2019-07-20" "2019-07-27" "2019-08-03" "2019-08-10" "2019-08-17"
```

Comment: the issue is that each participant has a different start date, will this still work?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by each `participant` and take difference of `RecorededDate` with the first `RecorededDate` to count number of weeks.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- mydata %>%
            group_by(participant) %>%
            mutate(time1 = ceiling(as.numeric(difftime(RecorededDate, 
                                    na.omit(RecorededDate)[1], units = 'week'))))
result
```

`RecorededDate` column should be of class Date.

Comment: When I try this I get the error "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time1`.
x Input `time1` can't be recycled to size 1.
ℹ Input `time1` is `ceiling(...)`.
ℹ Input `time1` must be size 1, not 2003.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: mydataframe$RecipientLastName = 1."

Comment: What is `class(mydata$RecorededDate)` ? 2) Try with `dplyr::mutate`. 3) Provide sample of your data using `dput(head(mydata))`.

Comment: the class is [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" , i get the same error when i use dplyr::mutate, however even when i did as.date(RecordedDate) I got the same error

Comment: There is not enough data to test this but you have lot of `NA` values. In `difftime` instead of `first(RecorededDate)` can you replace it with `na.omit(RecorededDate)[1]` and try. I have also updated the answer showing that.